# Redirect to new submitted post

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

I have a form, accessible by anyone with the link on my wordpress website. 
When the user submits the new post I want him to be redirected to the post they have just created.

Here is the form:

```
<?php 
wp_register_script( 'validation', 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'validation' );


$post_information = array(
    'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
    'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

wp_insert_post( $post_information );
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_information );
?>


<form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return getContent()">

<fieldset>
  <label for="postTitle"><?php _e('Post Title:', 'framework') ?></label>

  <input type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" class="required" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <label for="postContent"><?php _e('Post Content:', 'framework') ?></label>
  <textarea name="postContent" id="postContent" rows="8" cols="30" class="required"></textarea>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

  <button type="submit"><?php _e('Add Post', 'framework') ?></button>
  <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

I thought that by adding this

```
wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
die();
```

to the end of the PHP code it would redirect the user to the post they have created... I've tried different things but it doesn't work.It doesn't redirect anywhere.
Do you have any ideas? How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are repeating the insert. that may be an issue. try this.. it SHOULD work

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);
$url = get_permalink( $post_id );
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you Ralph for your answer. I've just tried, and the entire website is now blank, nothing appears anymore (html etc.). It seems to be related to "exit();", as soon as I delete it it works again (but not the redirection). Do you know why it's doing that? thanks!

Comment: you can replace by Die(), but it should not matter what you use. die is an alias for exit :/

Comment: if this does not work i will need better context, as it could fail depending on where you try to accomplish this. are you trying this from a template? a plugin?, the functions file? what triggers your code to be executed. presence of a post element?

Comment: Hi Ralph! Thanks for your help, I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687913/functions-php-with-wp-redirecturl-exit-makes-wordpress-site-blank